# Como es que se almacenan numeros sumamente grandes en memoria?

Tags: python

-La pregunta es sencilla: como hace Python para almacenar numeros sumamente grandes en memoria, en otras palabras ...

```
def factorial(n):
    facto = 1
    while n > 0:
        facto = facto*n
        n-=1
    return facto

print(factorial(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
```

-Como es que esto funciona ?. Se supone que un numero de tal magnitud jamas cabria en un solo espacio de la memoria...

***Aclaratoria:*** propongo el ejemplo en Python, ya que es el unico lenguaje que conozco que es capaz de hacer que se almacenen numeros demasiado grandes, jamas he logrado hacer algo asi con C por ejemplo, de hecho en C, empleando el tipo de dato mas grande (`long double`) este no es capaz de almacenar un resultado de tal magnitud. En caso de que alguien pueda hacer algun codigo en `C` que logre hacer que se  almacene un numero asi en memoria, seria pertinente que lo estableciera como respuesta

Comment: IMHO (In My Humilde Opinion) no creo que quepa todo, parece que desde cierto punto el resultado del factorial empieza a ser todo 000000... Pero esperemos una respuesta de alguien que sepa más de Python que yo.

Comment: Lo que yo dije NO reemplaza la repuesta de alguien que sepa más que yo.

Comment: Python tiene acceso a la memoria (Hardware)???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez mmmm si, como cualquier otro lenguaje de programacion :/

Comment: Python no tiene acceso al Harware, quien lo tiene es la maquina Virtual de Python que se ejecutan en lenguaje C, entonces el lenguaje C es quien si tiene acceso a lenguaje de maquina, y convierte las instrucciones en este lenguaje especifico que es quien gestiona la memoria...

Comment: en tal caso la pregunta seria: como gestiona en lenguaje de maquina la memoria RAM para guardar números enteros demasiado largos.

Comment: Para saber eso tendras que ver la implemetacion. Hay varias librerias en C y C++ que estan destinadas a trabajar con numeros grandes, puede que hecharles un vistaso te de una idea.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Muy técnico pues. La pregunta se entiende perfectamente de la forma en la que la escribió. Al tratar de corregir la pregunta en lugar de explicar una respuesta no ayudas en nada. De hecho ni siquiera es correcta tu correccion porque dejas al aire lo de "demaciado largos".

Comment: @Pablochaches el mismo OP uso eltermino "numeros sumamente grandes"

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Tu fuiste el que trato de corregirlo. El hizo una pregunta que se entiende bien. Tu quisiste colocarte todo técnico, y solo señale que 1. Eso no es útil y 2. Omitiste detalles.

Comment: la Respuesta real es que Python no Gestiona Memoria para "números que son sumamente grandes"; python envía la instrucción a la Maquina Virtual que esta escrita en C o puede ser otro lenguaje, para que esta la gestione la instrucciones en lenguaje de maquina que harán la conversiones y asignación de índices y espacios de memoria (hardrware)... en términos técnico, primero se toma el string se transforma a entero y luego dependiendo del tamaño se van generando espacios de memoria lo suficientes para que el dato se guarde en RAM.

Comment: Ves, eso es mucho mejor que tratar de corregir su pregunta.

Comment: Si quieres ver como lo implementa cpython. Puede que quieras hecharle un vistaso a [la documentacion en su repositorio](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/c-api/number.rst)

Comment: Un agregado: aunque python soporta una cantidad grande de números enteros no lo hace con números decimales, pero como solución esta la función decimal() la cual le puedes pasar un string con el numero deseado, doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: @PySanti hay te deje mi respuesta por si quieres profundizar mas en el tema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En *Python 2.7* se diferenciaba entre *int* y *long int*. Para el caso de *int* se ocupan 32 bits, mientras que el caso de *long int* no está restringido por por el número de bits, sino que se puede expandir por toda la memoria (hasta alcanzar su límite).

A partir de *Python 3* solo se tiene un tipo de dato que es *int* y comprenden los dos tipos explicados.

Aquí puedes encontrar algo de más información: [Doing Math in Python](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mitra/csSpring2016/cs313/lectures/math.html)

También puedes consultar este artículo en el que explica detalladamente cómo se pueden guardar tales número en memoria: [How python implements super long integers?](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/how-python-implements-super-long-integers-12icwon5vk)

Answer (score 10):

En C los enteros tienen un tamaño prefijado por el compilador y elegido por el programador, mediante las palabras reservadas `short` (16 bits), `long` (32 bits) o `long long` (64 bits).

Obviamente un tamaño prefijado impone un límite, que es de 2 elevado al número de bits (para los enteros `unsigned`) o bien elevado al número de bits menos 1 (para los enteros con signo).

Así, por ejemplo, en un dato de tipo `unsigned long int` (32 bits), el dato más grande que cabe es 2<sup>32</sup>. Si sumas 1 a ese dato, obtienes como resultado cero (y en la ALU se activaría el bit de carry, pero ese hecho sería ignorado, y en definitiva tendrías un resultado erróneo).

En **Python** en cambio la implementación es más inteligente. Por defecto los enteros comienzan siendo de 32 bits, pero cuando se va a hacer cualquier operación con enteros, el intérprete determina de antemano si el resultado cabrá o no en 32 bits (por ejemplo si se van a multiplicar dos enteros de 32 bits es probable que el resultado no quepa, pues puede llegar a requerir hasta 64 bits).

Cuando el intérprete detecta que el resultado no cabrá en 32 bits, lo "aumenta". En realidad lo que ocurre es que el entero es implementado mediante un array de `unsigned long int`, y cada uno de esos elementos almacena una única "cifra" del entero a almacenar, pero expresado en base 2<sup>30</sup>.

Por ejemplo, si el número es inferior a 2<sup>30</sup>, cabría en una única "cifra" (es decir, un único elemento del array), pero si es mayor, se redimensiona ese array para añadir más "cifras".

### Por ejemplo

Consideremos el resultado de `factorial(20)` que es:

```
2432902008176640000
```

Este número es mayor de 2<sup>30</sup> (que es `1073741824`), por lo que hay que pasarlo a base 1073741824  para encontrar sus cifras. La conversión consiste en dividir por 1073741824 para sacar las "decenas", y el resto de esa división serán las "unidades". En este caso sale:

- "Decenas" = `2432902008176640000 // 1073741824` = 2265816562
- "Unidades" = `2432902008176640000 % 1073741824` = 118332914

Como ves las unidades ya salen inferiores a 2<sup>30</sup> (no puede ser de otro modo por ser el resto de la división), pero las "decenas" aún salen superiores a 2<sup>30</sup>, por lo que hay que dividir de nuevo para obtener "centenas":

- "Centenas" = `2265816562 // 1073741824` = 2
- "Decenas" = `2265816562 % 1073741824` = 118332914 (casualmente en este caso es igual a las "unidades")
- "Unidades" = 118332914

Así que el número en cuestión ocupa tres "cifras" en base 2<sup>30</sup>, y por tanto se puede guardar en un array de 3 posiciones (en el que cada posición es de tipo `unsigned long int` en C).

Esta es la forma en que Python consigue guardar números de cualquier tamaño. A medida que el número crece, reserva dinámicamente memoria para más elementos en ese array, y por tanto para más "cifras".

Naturalmente operar con este tipo de números no es tan inmediato como operar con los tipos nativos del C. Cuando en C haces `a + b`, siendo `a` y `b` variables de tipo `long int`, en el fondo la operación se reduce a transferir esas variables a dos registros de la CPU y usar la ALU de la CPU para sumar esos registros, lo cual básicamente se resuelve en una sola operación ensamblador. En Python en cambio es necesaria toda una lógica que permita operar con los elementos del array antes explicado (las "cifras"), propagar el acarreo de una "cifra" a otra, etc.

No obstante si los datos que maneja el programa python son menores a 2<sup>30</sup>, ya que eso cabe en una sola "cifra", la operación se resolvería también en pocos ciclos de CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Tratare de Responder técnicamente (en castellano) tu pregunta ya que el ultimo punto que mencionas hace referencia a **espacio de memoria**, asumo que te refieres a Hardrware ya que no lo especificas:

***- como hace Python para almacenar números sumamente grandes:***

R. Python 3 solo se tiene un tipo de dato que es int y comprenden los tipos normales y long.

***- Como es que esto funciona ?. Se supone que un numero de tal magnitud jamas cabria en un solo espacio de la memoria***

R. Técnicamente Python (Lenguaje) no Gestiona la Memoria (Hardware) a usar para almacenar datos; este lenguaje le da la instrucción a la Maquina Virtual PWM o entorno de ejecución, que esta escrita en C para que se comunique con el Hardware (CPU y Memoria), para que en lenguaje de maquina (***Bytecode*** en este caso) se trate el tipo de dato y la Memoria.

También la Maquina Virtual Maneja su propio espacio de memoria RAM Virtual por así decirlo y puede ser aun mayor a la Memoria RAM Física.

**Enteros:** para este caso si un espacio de memoria no es suficiente, cosa que suele pasar, el sistema creara un índice (array) de memoria que guardara el numero partido por espacios, y este es dinámico. puede tener un entero guardado en 128b y otro numero entero que ocupe 256b en Memoria.

**Un ejemplo seria el siguiente:**

Antes de guardar el dato, la maquina virtual en lenguaje de maquina debe validar si existe el espacio suficiente para que el hardrware o RAM Virtual guarde la informacion; evitando un overflow de memoria y un crash del sistema. python no solicita esto; esto es ejecutado internamente entre la maquina virtual, el lenguaje de maquina y el hardrware, la maquina virtual provocara una excepción o tipo de error si detecta que no tiene la capacidad (no se que tan raro que ocurra).

y se llama **Bytecode**

```
1         0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
          2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

2         4 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 34)
    >>    6 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
          8 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
         10 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
         12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32 

3        14 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
         16 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
         18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 
         20 POP_TOP                    

4        22 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
         24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
         26 INPLACE_ADD                
         28 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
         30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6 
    >>   32 POP_BLOCK                  
    >>   34 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
         36 RETURN_VALUE
```

Entonces hasta donde entiendo CPython no hace JIT de fábrica, pero puede obtener un JIT simple para CPython con numba.

Además, hay al menos una implementación del lenguaje Python con JIT está lista para usar: Pypy o Shedskin o pyrex.

(Un "JIT" convierte el código de bytes en código de máquina para mejorar el rendimiento)

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

***Aclaro:*** no soy un experto en Python, pero es importante que conozcamos la teoría de como funcionan nuestros lenguajes de programación y parte o todo "su trasfondo" y no solo el escribir el código.

Link relacionados:

https://leanpub.com/insidethepythonvirtualmachine/read
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-python/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892575/4717133
https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-python-bytecode-e7edaae8734d
https://caiocozza-art.medium.com/a-quick-overview-of-the-python-virtual-machine-pt-1-315e74c036f4
https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/interpreter.html